# non-objetc_laravel5.8_error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, object

Buen día, mi problema es que al tratar de traer un campo de una tabla asociada 
"clientes_nom" y mostrarlo junto con los otros datos de la tabla me lanza un error "non-object", agradecería cualquier ayuda posible. estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto blog de laravel 5.8 sin mayores cambios. uso una base de datos en mysql.

Estos son mis modelos:
este es el modelo padre Cliente, algo muy sencillo.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tb_clientes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'clientes_id';
    protected $fillable = ['clientes_nom','clientes_email'];
    public function pedidos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pedido');
    }
}
```

y este es el modelo de la tabla hijo Pedido, con algunos datos.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Pedido extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tb_pedidos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'producto_cod';
    protected $fillable = ['producto_nom','producto_presentacion','producto_cant','producto_val','producto_asesor','producto_cli'];
    public function clientes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'clientes_id');
    }
}
```

Este es el código del controlador:
por ahora solo tiene el recurso del index.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Pedido;
use App\Cliente;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ItemCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ItemUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use DB;
use Input;
use Storage;
class PedidosController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
  return $this->listarPedido();
}
public function create(){
  return $this->crearPedido();
}
public function edit($id){
  return $this->editarPedido($id);
}
public function destroy($id){
  return $this->eliminarPedido($id);
}
public function listarPedido(){
  $pedidos = Pedido::all();
  //dd($pedidos);
  return view('negocio.pedido.index', compact('pedidos'));
}
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    }
    public function show(Cliente $cliente)
    {
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Cliente $cliente)
    {
    }
}
```

y este es el código de la vista:
una tabla que me permite enseñar los datos que se encuentran en la tabla, mediante un foreach y eso es todo hasta ahora.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Listar Pedido</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vista Listado Pedidos</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>CODIGO</th>
        <th>PRODUCTO</th>
        <th>PRESENTACION</th>
        <th>CANTIDAD</th>
        <th>VALOR</th>
        <th>ASESOR</th>
        <th>CLIENTE</th>
        <
      </tr>
      @foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_cod}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_nom}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_presentacion}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_cant}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_val}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->producto_asesor}}</td>
        <td>{{$pedido->clientes->clientes_nom}}</td><!--quiero traer el nombre de la tabla asociada y no me deja-->
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Migraciones.............

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateClientesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('clientes_id');
            $table->string('clientes_nom');
            $table->string('clientes_email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clientes');
    }
}
```

y esta es la migración de tb_pedidos

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreatePedidosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('producto_cod');
            $table->string('producto_nom');
            $table->string('producto_presentacion');
            $table->double('producto_cant',8,0);
            $table->double('producto_val');
            $table->string('producto_asesor');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('producto_cli');
            $table->foreign('producto_cli')->references('clientes_id')->on('tb_clientes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pedidos');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la migración de las dos tablas involucradas?

Comment: ya la edite la pregunta

Comment: en tu controlador haz la consulta a DB así: `$pedidos = Pedido::with('clientes')->all();`

Comment: disculpa. usa `->get()` en vez de `->all()`. `$pedidos = Pedido::with('clientes')->get();`

Comment: ¿ cambiaste el nombre de la relación de clientes a cliente como te dice Shaz? Si es así usa `Pedido::with('cliente')->get();`

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [clientes] on model [App\Pedido].                                   me devolvió esto, trate de cambiar "clientes" por "cliente" y de nuevo sale esto:                                                                                                           
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\webServices\blog\resources\views\negocio\pedido\index.blade.php)

Comment: en la vista usa lo mismo que tengas en la relación, si es cliente usa cliente, si es clientes usa clientes. Como te mencionó shaz en la respuesta tiene mas sentido que sea "cliente" y no "clientes", ya que es uno solo

Comment: o sea en la vista usa:  `{{$pedido->clientes->clientes_nom}}` o `{{$pedido->cliente->clientes_nom}}`. Como sea que estés definiendo la relación en el modelo: `public function clientes()` o `public function cliente()`

Comment: éxito!!, les agradezco mucho su ayuda, no entiendo el porque de la falla, estaba siguiendo un tutorial paso a paso en youtube; pero me han salvado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que es una relación one-to-many y siguiendo las convenciones de Laravel y los nombres de los campos que tienes, debería ser así la definición de la relación:

```
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'producto_cli', 'clientes_id');
}
```

y el nombre del cliente se obtendría así:

```
{{$pedido->clientes->clientes_nom}}
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la atención.                                                                                                      Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()...    
después de agregar lo que dijiste al controlador me salio esto.

Comment: Lo que puse en la respuesta no es para el controlador, es para el modelo y la vista respectivamente.

Comment: perdón no vi bien era el aporte de otro usuario, aun así les agradezco mucho su ayuda.